# How to set permissions for Ruby script executed by php form action

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, digital-ocean

There are four files I'm dealing with here:

```
master_form.php
action.php
form.txt
program.rb
```

So, data are inputted into `master_form.php` and passed through `action.php` via POST to generate `form.txt`, which is tab delimited file with the form data inputted from `master_form.php`. Now, `action.php` first generates the `.txt` file and then executes `program.rb` which uses the tab delimited file `form.txt`. All this is going on, and I'm just not sure how to write permissions, you know, like what's best, so nobody's intercepting things or ripping source, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you want to keep any `.rb` type files outside of your web root since you don't want them being served up. Often this means structuring your application with a `public/` directory where the main PHP files live, and a `lib/` or `bin/` directory for scripts like that.

Only things in the `public/` directory are executable by your PHP server, and generally `.php` files are executed. There's still a small risk that for some reason PHP will be disabled and it will serve up source code so never, ever put sensitive credentials in those files. Always include that from another path, like `config/` in the parent directory of `public/`.

When you execute your Ruby script, be sure to specify the proper path and it'll run as you expect.

Comment: So if I put the Ruby file in `lib/` and `action.php` is called, it would need to be called like this: `system('ruby /lib/program.rb');` in PHP, right? Right now, `program.rb` has this permission architecture: `-rw-r--r--`

Comment: Probably more like `ruby ../lib/program.rb` presuming the script's working directory is the script's directory. You may have to experiment.

Comment: I got this with your suggestion: `ruby: No such file or directory -- ../lib/program.rb (LoadError)
`

Comment: You'll have to find out what your working directory is, then adjust that path accordingly. Web servers handle that in a variety of ways.

Comment: Yeah, I tried `/lib/program.rb` but got [this](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/36186e143a24d636c653b31ba9fb6900) error.